# Deployment of .war reboot race condition

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, war, nsis

I've got an nsis install script that copies a `.war` file into the Tomcat `webapps` directory. If Tomcat is already running it will notice a new `.war` was dropped into the `webapps` dir and began unpacking it. However the unpack is happening in the background and the installer thinks it's done so it prompts the user to reboot. If the user chooses to reboot now then there is a very good chance Tomcat will get interrupted midway during the unpack of the `.war` and leave the webapp in a corrupted state.

The only solution I can think of is to stop the Tomcat service at the start of the installer (`net stop tomcat6`) to prevent Tomcat from unpacking the `.war`. Then on reboot the Tomcat service will start up and do it's unpack then. This seems dirty though because if the user chooses not to reboot immediately it leaves the Tomcat service stopped (which could be undesirable if there are other running webapps).

No matter which way I slice it it seems like Tomcat should recognize the webapp did not fully unpack and clean up after itself and try again. Tomcat bug?

Comment: Why does the installer need to reboot the box?

Comment: @Joe it's part of a larger install script that requires the reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You could [poll the currently deployed list of applications](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/manager-howto.html#List_Currently_Deployed_Applications) and disable the reboot option until you see your webapp being available.

If you don't like communicating via Ant/manager app, there's a fair chance of a similar JMX hook (I know there's similar one for JBoss at least). Even if there isn't one available out of the box, if should be fairly easy to write your own.

Comment: Thanks, I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't go outside of my existing installer script (nsis) or add extra deployment dependencies (ant).